# <video> responsive resolution both for mobile and desktop browser

Tags: css, html, video, responsive-design, webrtc

I have a simple question about the `<video>` tag.

I want to build a simple full screen video chat that runs on `PhoneGap` (mobile) and desktop browsers (`Chrome`).

What I need is the video to stay full screen both if it comes from a mobile camera or desktop browser camera. I guess they will have different aspect ratio and I don't understand how to merge the problem.

What I am afraid of is, when video comes from a mobile camera then how could it fit the entire browser screen (full screen) which is bigger?

I am sorry if I haven't tried anything yet, but I just would like to understand what to start with, the logic behind.

Any tip appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't wish to change aspect ratio of video, than you can only make full screen canvas. Video will still be shown in origin aspect ratio and around it will be black spaces. To make it full screen, use `width: 100%; height: 100%; position: fixed;`. Keep in mind that browser window not always is in common aspect ratio (16:9, 4:3 and so on) because you can view website in not maximized window. Than aspect ratio will be custom.

Comment: thank you, but does not the resolution of the mobile video will be ok on browser if in full screen? maybe better if find some mobile camera video and put it on the browser just to check, using position:fixed

Comment: @sbaaaang It depends on what resolution camera has. If you make video with camera of `1920x1080` it will be fine, but if you take first mobile that has camera at try to show that video, that it will look bad in any way. But I don't think you can change here something